# Confused between QSQLITE and SQLITE

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm a creating a music library manager on Qt. I'm confused whether I should use Qt's driver for SQLITE(QSqlite) or raw SQLITE that I just grabbed from their website. I'll need to create .dll from the raw code though. But if I use Qt's native library, I believe I'll have to install the drivers inorder to use the app on a different system.

I'm a newbie to both Qt and SQLITE. Any kind of help/advise would be awesome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Not the "drivers", no, you'll need to provide the Qt runtime system DLLs, unless you are a commercial user in which case you can statically link the Qt libraries.  If you write in Qt at all, this is the case, regardless of how you use sqlite.  But to answer your question, you need to go with QSQLITE.

Comment: I finally went with QSQLITE. It was a real time saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use the `QSQLITE` driver.

- It is part of Qt SQL module which provides support for SQL databases in a really "Qtish" way. You'll save a lot of time and effort.
- There's no need for additional installation. You just have to include the driver (sqldrivers/qsqlite.dll) in your deploy folder. After all, if you don't pay for a comercial license, when you deploy a Qt application you'll have to carry with several dynamic libraries. I don't think just one more will make a difference.